# where to start with Facebook development using asp.net

Tags: c#, facebook

I am new to Facebook development. Where do you think I should start learning. Do you know any good resources like videos, samples, books, blogs tutorials? I found some but they are quite old, and I don't want to waste my time with an old library if there is a new and more powerful one. Thanks!

Comment: http://developers.facebook.com/search?q=ASP.NET

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Facebook Developer ToolKit](http://facebooktoolkit.codeplex.com/)
[Facebook SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/ee388574)
[Facebook C# SDK](http://facebooksdk.codeplex.com/)

Comment: is there any book available for facebook development using c# / asp.net ??

Comment: @Yasser, both Facebook Developer Toolkit and Facebook SDK have good documentations. It's good enough to start with them.

Answer (score 1):

In my opion it is best to implement everything server side with no javascript.
I did not care for any of the C# SDK's so I am "rolling "my own using a few simple classes and such.

The link I have included does point to one of the SDK's however is still a good starting point.

http://www.atlasbay.com/2010/04/21/new-facebook-connect-in-csharp/